# Add percent to ngModel value Angular 6 (pipe)

Tags: angular, pipe, angular2-ngmodel

I would like to have value in input (from ngModel) and in the end have percent symbol '%'. When I try do it using custom pipe, on the begining everything is fine, but when I remove value from input and change it, this percent is added every time you enter the keyboard. How can I change it? I need allow type eg '40' and after this add '%', no immediately after '4'.
Example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppkbwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Add a conditional check   if (val &&

Comment: u can try this alternate approach without using pipes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e96k2u

Answer (score 1):

```
@Pipe({ name: 'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(val) {
    if(String(val) === ''){
        return val;
    }else if (String(val).indexOf('%') === -1) {
        return val + '%';
    } else {
        return val
    }
   }
}
```

i think you should have an extra if condition at first to check that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pipes for that. You can implement it using `(focusout)` on your input field

```
<input (focusin)="start($event)" (focusout)="end($event)" type="text" />
```

In your ts file

```
start(e){
    if(e.target.value.indexOf('%') < 0)
    e.target.value =  e.target.value + '%';}
end(e){
   e.target.value = e.target.value.replace('%','');}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the `%` first. Like this (assuming you have always numbers you want to show with the % sign):

```
@Pipe({ name: 'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(val) {
        debugger

        val = val.replace('%','');

        if (String(val).indexOf('%') === -1) {
            return val + '%';
        } else {
            return val
        }
    }
}
```